# We weren't able to verify your property: www.website.com

Tags: wordpress, amazon-ec2, web, ubuntu-14.04, google-search-console

While using `GoogleWebMaster` for verifying a newly uploaded website I get this error when I use a HTML upload verification type.

> > We weren't able to verify your property: www.website.com

My server is a EC2, ubuntu 64 bit micro instance running apache2.

Answer (score 0):

I moved the file to `/var/www/html` and yet the verification failed. I then used `chown` to change the ownership of the file. It worked after that.

> > sudo chown www-data:www-data google.html